# Flutter: loading Firestore data into Provider at app initialization

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, deserialization

I am working on an app with a Firestore db backend, since I don't have to update anything from the app and data is quite static, I would like to deserialize ALL Firestore data into a Dart data structure at app initialization (ideally into a Provider) in order to avoid having Future/StreamBuilders all over my Widget classes.

Data in Firestore is structured as

```
Route
|->Room
   |->Point of Interest
```

This is the Provider class

```
class AppData with ChangeNotifier {
  static final FirebaseRepo _repo = new FirebaseRepo();

  List<model.Route> _routes;

  List<model.Route> get routes => _routes;

  set routes(List<model.Route> routes) {
    _routes = routes;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  AppData() {
    _loadData();
  }

  Future<void> _loadData() async {
    routes = await _repo.findAllRoutes();
  }

  // some get methods that operate on _routes
}
```

this is an excerpt from the repository class in which I load `routes`

```
class FirebaseRepo {
  FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  Source _dbSource = Source.cache;

  Future<List<model.Route>> findAllRoutes() async {
    List<model.Route> routes = [];
    var routeContent = await _db.collection('content')
        .where("type", isEqualTo: "route")
        .orderBy("order", descending: false)
        .get(GetOptions(source: _dbSource));

    if (routeContent.docs.length > 0) {
      await Future.forEach(routeContent.docs, (snapshot) async {
        model.Route route = await loadRouteFromSnapshot(snapshot);
        route.rooms = await findRouteRooms(route.id);
        routes.add(route);
      });
    }

    return routes;
  }

  Future<List<Room>> findRouteRooms(String routeId) async {
    List<Room> rooms = [];
    var roomContent = await _db.collection('content')
        .doc(routeId)
        .collection("rooms")
        .orderBy("order", descending: false)
        .get(GetOptions(source: _dbSource));

    if (roomContent.docs.length > 0) {
      await Future.forEach(roomContent.docs, (snapshot) async {
        Room room = await loadRoomFromSnapshot(snapshot, routeId);
        room.pois = await findRoomPois(room.parentRouteId, room.id);
        rooms.add(room);
      });
    }

    return rooms;
  }

  Future<List<Poi>> findRoomPois(String routeId, String roomId) async {
    List<Poi> pois = [];
    var poiContent = await _db.collection('content')
        .doc(routeId)
        .collection("rooms")
        .doc(roomId)
        .collection("poi")
        .orderBy("order", descending: false)
        .get(GetOptions(source: _dbSource));

    if (poiContent.docs.length > 0) {
      await Future.forEach(poiContent.docs, (snapshot) async {
        Poi poi = await loadPoiFromSnapshot(snapshot, routeId, roomId);
        pois.add(poi);
      });
    }

    return pois;
  }

................
}
```

and this is the main class

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(CatedralApp());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
        fontFamily: 'Alata',
      ),
      routes: {
        RouteDetail.routeName: (context) => RouteDetail(),
        RoomDetail.routeName: (context) => RoomDetail(),
        PoiDetail.routeName: (context) => PoiDetail(),
      },
      home: LoadingScreen()
    );
  }
}

class LoadingScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: AppData(),
      child: Consumer<AppData> (
        builder: (BuildContext context, AppData provider, Widget child) {
          if (provider.routes != null) {
            return Home();
          } else {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/img/splash_background.png'),
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/img/icon.png',
                    height: 200,
                    width: 200,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The idea is to show the splashscreen while data is loading, and then go to the Home view, I've tried some variations of the above code but it doesnt seem to work, data in the Provider is always an empty list, I honestly don't even know if what I want to do is "right" for how Flutter apps are supposed to work but I'm trying to understand as much as I can...

As far as I tested, reading from cache is not a problem, since it tries cache and then moves to `Source.server` (but I tried it with `Source.server` and it doesn't work anyway), when there is already cached data the app works fine, and by debugging it when no cache data is present the repositories methods actually retrieve data from Firestore, so connection with the db is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out that I was wrong on reading from cache, the right way to do this (obviously if you **always** want to force reading from cache) is

```
Future<List<model.Route>> findAllRoutes() async {
    List<model.Route> routes = [];
    var routeContent = await _db.collection('content')
        .where("type", isEqualTo: "route")
        .orderBy("order", descending: false)
        .get(GetOptions(source: Source.Cache));

    if (routeContent.docs.length > 0) {
      ...
    } else {
      routeContent = await _db.collection('content')
        .where("type", isEqualTo: "route")
        .orderBy("order", descending: false)
        .get(GetOptions(source: Source.Server));
      ...
    }

    return routes;
  }
```

this method tries to read from cache and then reads from the server, so on first app run it will read from server, and then on subsequent runs it will always read from cache, I hope this can help someone :) anyway, if you have some observation over this whole solution it will be greatly appreciated!